# Sumbission of answer to CMI

Tags: prime-numbers

I am very interested in maths and believe to have solved one of the millenial problems. I can understand half of the problems and the other half mean nothing to me but I think I have solved the problem about distribution of primes among natural numbers (The Riemann Hypothesis). I have worked out a formula (which I'm not showing here for obvious reasons) but how will I have to present it to the CMI. Should I just give them the formula or explain why the formula is and why there is a link between prime numbers (which I haven't worked out yet).

Comment: Which of the millennium problems would that be? The Riemann hypothesis seems to come closest to what you claim, and that also matches that you were not even able to understand the entirety of the problem. The likelyhood of your solution being even remotely correct is zero since you did not even understand the problem.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I must have got you confused. It is the Riemann hypothesis (which I understand fully). I meant I couldn't understand half of the questions. I'll edit my question.

Comment: You understand the Riemann hypothesis, but your solution involved having "worked out a formula"? A formula for what?

Comment: A different formula that proves that proves the Riemann Zeta function correct.

Comment: The Riemann hypothesis is not about the zeta functiong being "correct" in any meaningful sense.

Comment: No but it was proved that there is a link between primes but they don't know what. I know what.

Comment: What? The link between the Rieman zeta function and the distribution of primes is very well known. The problem is proving certain properties of the zeroes of the zeta function in order to make conclusions about this distribution.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Exactly

Answer (score 3):

Even though I highly doubt that you actually solved one of the millenium problems, I will still give you an answer. The CMI has certain rules for the millenium prizes. All rules are listed [here](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/rules-millennium-prizes).

Most important to you will be this part:

> Before consideration, a proposed solution must be published in a
>   refereed mathematics publication of worldwide repute (or such other
>   form as the SAB shall determine qualifies), and it must also have
>   general acceptance in the mathematics community two years after.

Hence, you pick your favorite high quality journal, hand in your proof, wait until it is refereed and accepted, wait for two years and the one million dollars are yours. I wish you best of luck!

Comment: What is a millenium question... I haven't heard about it?

Comment: It's a list of six (originally seven) problems, each worth one million dollars issued by the Clay Mathematics Institute if you solve one. The seventh problem has been solved by Grigori Perelman in 2003. You can find the whole list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems

Comment: In 2000 the clay mathematics institute set seven "apparently unsolvable" questions, offering $1 million for anyone who could solve one. Since then, only one has been solved

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: @YukiJ thanks for the answer

Comment: @WilliamPennanti You are welcome! :)

Comment: I find it impossible to believe that you've "solved" a Millennium Problem when the other "half [of the problems] mean nothing to me."